# How to add new language to "sys.fulltext_languages" in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, language

how can I add new language (1045 - Polish) to "sys.fulltext_languages" table in SQL Server 2008?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [MSDN document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345188.aspx) shows how to load a third party word breaker into SQL 2008.  The document references Danish, Polish and Turkish.